# DDD: Aggregate boundary vs compositional convenience.

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm starting a new DDD project and I feel like I haven't really grasped the concepts yet. I have a two aggregate roots in my domain so far, `Recipe` and `Food`. Their relationship is like this :

```
`Recipe`->*`Ingredient`->`Food`
```

An `Ingredient` is a quantity + a `Food`

I think that maybe having the aggregate (`Food`) in the `Recipe` aggregate is bad, but it's really convenient because it allows to calculate the nutritional values of a recipe by navigating the relation.

I also do not store the result of the calculation and I recalculate every time so if a food is changed the recipe is updated automatically and I don't know if it's a good idea.

Also, is it Ok to have a single repository for `Recipe`+`Ingredient` since they are in the same aggregate and I have to load all the ingredients so I can pass them in the constructor of the recipe anyway?

Comment: If you are inventing your own project for learning DDD, "editing" is a really lousy domain to start from.  Look for something where the model gets to make decisions for itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it Ok to have a single repository for Recipe+Ingredient since they are in the same aggregate and I have to load all the ingredients so I can pass them in the constructor of the recipe anyway?

That is what most people would expect - a single repository that loads all of the state contained within an aggregate boundary.

> I think that maybe having the aggregate (Food) in the Recipe aggregate is bad, but it's really convenient because it allows to calculate the nutritional values of a recipe by navigating the relation.

- The bad outweighs the good.
- This is not obvious when using a simplified domain to discover how to DDD.

The motivation for aggregates is to constrain the way the data in your model changes, so that every change leaves the model in an internally consistent state.

If your domain doesn't have any consistency constraints to enforce (for instance, when your data model is really just a database, and the data model has no veto power over proposed changes), then the problem space doesn't offer a lot of guidance in choosing good aggregate boundaries.

The basic principle behind aggregates is that you are creating a sort of data firewall, you never need to worry that changes to *this* aggregate are going to violate the rules of *that* aggregate.  This implies, among other things, that no two aggregates should ever share mutable data.

Sharing values is fine -- each aggregate gets its own immutable copy of a value, and changing the value in one aggregate doesn't affect the other at all.  Sharing entities is bad, because entities are mutable.

Having a model that makes it really convenient to produce a query with the wrong answers isn't as valuable as a model that ensures that the answers are correct.

What will normally happen is that one aggregate will reference another by ID.  So your recipe would look like

```
`Recipe`->*`Ingredient`->`Id<Food>`
```

`Id<Food>` is just another immutable value type; the recipe can easily change which food it uses, but it can't change the food in any way.  Which in turn means that you never need to worry that changing one `Recipe` will break another.

Comment: How do I access the Food proprieties from then? Do I have them all copied over in Ingredient?

Comment: If your aggregate boundaries are drawn correctly, you never need to modify Food when changing a Recipe.  If you are responding to a query, your implementation is read only and you don't need to worry about changing anything, just load the Recipe, and then enumerate the Id<Food> to load the Food.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answer here. The way I see it Food is never going to change when I edit a recipe or an ingredient (ie if I want to change a food in a recipe I need to delete the ingredient and add a new one). What do you mean by load the Recipe and then load the Food? How does the ingredients access the Food from there?

Comment: @Cedric There are several ways to approach this problem. Reads don't usually go through the domain model as the domain model is optimized for processing commands rather than to facilitate reads. If you want to know how much carbs a recipe has per portion for instance that could be a simple calculation done on the query side. If the calculation is very complex and you would like to keep it in the model then perhaps holding the result of the calculation in an aggregate would be best. In that case you need a way to perform it in the domain model in the first place.

Comment: Since Recipe and Ingredient are independent aggregates you would have to use a mechanism that allows you to recalculate the nutrition facts of a recipe in an eventual consistent manner. When Food nutrition facts are changing (would that ever happen?) then a FoodNutritionFactsChanged event could be published. You would then have a subscriber that would call upon a domain service which could load the Food and call `receipe.recalculateNutritionFacts(food)`. There are several possible implementations to achieve this. Do not forget that all receipes would have to get updated in a different transact